# Question on Google Maps integration

Tags: api, web-applications, google-maps

I am working on a webapplication where I need to deliver products to houses in my country.

All the street names and neighborhoods are present in Google maps. I want to know if there is any way to get all the street data(street name, region) from Google maps into one single file to load in my database.

This way people can easily find there street with the auto-suggest options Javascript has. And then I can calculate the cost, trough distance, the people have to pay.

Or is there another way to use the Google maps data in my web application.

PS. sorry for this not being a programming question. If someone knows another place on StackExchange where I can get this question better answered this post can be relocated.

Comment: you can get the travel distance from google map's direction service. it gives you the distance in miles and etc

Comment: Is this in api I can integrate on my website?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getting everything in a database is not something Google is going to give you. It's taken them a lot of effort to build it and they want some return.

You do have the option of working with [GeoNames](http://www.geonames.org) where you can either download the database or use a webservice.

Alternatively, you could access Google's database using the [Google Geocoding API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/).

I would recommend working with the Google version as it is much more likely to be up to date.

Comment: +1 You have a good point by suggesting to use the google database. If there are any updated they will be available on my website also. I will look into the links you supplied.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a way to calculate driving distance from one address to another so you could calculate costs, then I recommend you check out [this article](http://briancray.com/2009/06/23/calculate-driving-distance-google-maps-api/). Actually, I'm going to do exactly that on my current project. The problem is that we do not have specific addressing system in my country, so I'll have to use approximate estimations (within an area of the address that is...).